# How to add a label to the x / y axis whenever a vertical / horizontal line is added to a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-hline, geom-vline

The x and y axis are labeled based on certain interval set by ggplot.

In the event that a horizontal or vertical line is added to the plot, the goal is to label x or y axis at the exact value of the line.

How can this be done?

Comment: do you want these instead of or as well as the existing ticks?

Comment: as well as the existing ticks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't totally straightforward, but it is possible. I would probably use these two little functions to automate the tricky parts:

```r
add_x_break <- function(plot, xval) {
  
  p2 <- ggplot_build(plot)
  breaks <- p2$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x$breaks
  breaks <- breaks[!is.na(breaks)]
  
  plot +
    geom_vline(xintercept = xval) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = sort(c(xval, breaks)))
}

add_y_break <- function(plot, yval) {
  
  p2 <- ggplot_build(plot)
  breaks <- p2$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y$breaks
  breaks <- breaks[!is.na(breaks)]
  
  plot +
    geom_hline(yintercept = yval) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = sort(c(yval, breaks)))
}
```

These would work like this. Start with a basic plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = runif(10))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  ylim(0, 1)

p
```

[image]

Add a vertical line with `add_x_break`

```r
p <- add_x_break(p, 6.34)

p
```

[image]

Add a horizontal line with `add_y_break`:

```r
p <- add_y_break(p, 0.333)
#> Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will
#> replace the existing scale.

p
```

[image]

---

**ADDENDUM**

If for some reason you do not have the code that generated the plot, or the vline is already present, you could use the following function to extract the xintercept and add it to the axis breaks:

```r
add_x_intercepts <- function(p) {
  
  p2 <- ggplot_build(p)
  breaks <- p2$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x$breaks
  breaks <- breaks[!is.na(breaks)]
  
  vals <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(p$layers), function(x) {
    d <- layer_data(p, x)
    if('xintercept' %in% names(d)) d$xintercept else numeric()
  }))
  
  p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = sort(c(vals, breaks)))
}
```

So, for example:

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = runif(10))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 6.34) +
  ylim(0, 1)

p
```

[image]

Then we can do:

```r
add_x_intercepts(p)
```

[image]

The y intercepts of `geom_hline` can be obtained in a similar way, which should hopefully be evident from the code of `add_x_intercepts`

Comment: What if all we have is the plot? The line has been added, but we now don't have the value of the line?