# How to manually add a tick mark in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am quite new to the `ggplot2` world in R, so I am trying to get familiar with the technicalities of plotting with `ggplot2`. In particular, I have a problem, which can be replicated by the following MWE:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(1:10), y = c(1:10)), aes(x = c(1:10), y = c(1:10))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 6), lty = 2)
```

This generates a simple graph of a diagonal line with a horizontal dashed line that cuts the y-axis at 6.

I would like to know whether there is a way to add a tick mark of 6 on the y-axis? In other words, say I simply showed this plot to a person without the code. I want the person to know that the horizontal dashed line cuts the y-axis at 6, which is not easily seen since 6 is not labelled currently.

Any intuitive suggestions will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scale_y_continuous` and give it all the points where you'd want a tick in the `breaks` argument.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(1:10), y = c(1:10)), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 6), lty = 2) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10))
```

in this specific example there is lots of "empty space" and you might consider adding the number within the plot using `geom_text` or `geom_label` if you think that is, what people should take away from your plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(1:10), y = c(1:10)), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 6), lty = 2) + 
  #scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)) +
  geom_label(aes(x=2, y=6, label = "line at y = 6.0"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data frame

```
    df <- data.frame(x = c(1:10), y = c(1:10))
    
    #Plotting 
    p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
      geom_point() 
p
```

Custom function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71339547/how-to-add-a-label-to-the-x-y-axis-whenever-a-vertical-horizontal-line-is-ad)

It creates both x and y breaks

```
add_x_break <- function(plot, xval) {
  
  p2 <- ggplot_build(plot)
  breaks <- p2$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x$breaks
  breaks <- breaks[!is.na(breaks)]
  
  plot +
    geom_vline(xintercept = xval) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = sort(c(xval, breaks)))
}

add_y_break <- function(plot, yval) {
  
  p2 <- ggplot_build(plot)
  breaks <- p2$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y$breaks
  breaks <- breaks[!is.na(breaks)]
  
  plot +
    geom_hline(yintercept = yval) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = sort(c(yval, breaks)))
}
```

Define your break in your case `y break`

```
p <- add_y_break(p, 6)
p
```

Hope this helps

A bit of improvement with the ticks

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(df$x), max(df$x), by = 0.5),1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(df$y), max(df$y), by = 0.5),1))

p

p <- add_y_break(p, 6)
p
```

Comment: This doesn't really work, because the custom function is simply adding a solid line over my dashed line? Is there a way to tweak it so it follows the line type of the line I have added, in this case, dashed?

Comment: yes i didn't address that the other answer helps I guess the function can be tweaked to do the same